# Need to write a trigger before insert to check the distance between two lattitude longitude

Tags: mysql, dictionary, triggers

I have a table with field `tracks_date`, `tracks_time`, `tracks_lat`, `tracks_lon`, `user_id`
I have a GPS device and it update the latitude and longitude value along with the time and date.

The interval of insert is every 2 minutes. I dont want to insert record if the distance between the last inserted coordinates and the new coordinates to be less than 25mts.

I can do that in my php page but every time i have to pull the last record and compare before insert. So is it possible to do it in a trigger?

Thank you

Comment: when you say "last record" do you mean the record immediately prior, or the last inserted? did you only want to do this validation *per user*? Either way, you probably want to consider what would happen if the requests got handled out of order *for whatever reason*

Comment: Yes, Per user. And last record is indeed the last record of that particular user

Comment: last inserted, or last by date/time? (i.e. how should it behave when restoring a backup, in a random order)

Comment: If you have the last record in the application, it is faster to do the check there.  The database will have to find that record and then do the comparison.  You don't mention the number of users, but this could be adding a noticeable load on the server.

Comment: So you recommend to code it in php before i set off the insert query? Users will go upto 1000. 
By the way it depends on the date and time. The latest date and time will always be the last inserted since i am taking the date and time of the server.

Comment: Sorry i Miss-read you. I was wondering why i didn't thought of that. My Bad. Thanks anyway brother.